# What files of a meteor project I should push to a Git repo?

Tags: javascript, css, git, meteor

I have a created a meteor project via command `meteor create my-app` and then I have added some package like `meteor add some-package`. So in my project directory I have one CSS, one JS and one HTML file, also I have `.meteor` directory.

So now I want to add my project to a Git repo. So what all files I have add to my repo. I'm sure that I have to add css, js and html files. Do I have to add `.meteor` directory as well, if not then how someone get all packages related to my project after cloning it and make it working.

What is the correct approach to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only directory you want excluded from version control is .meteor/local.
Meteor automatically creates .gitignore in the .meteor directory.

[image: .gitignore]

Comment: So when someone cloned my project what command that user should run to get package dependencies and then run `meteor` to make it working?

Comment: OK. Let me try and check it!